# Change item template of widget after initialization

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there a way to change widget (specifically combobox) template after initializing it?

I tried

```
var combo = $("#combo").data("kendoComboBox");
var template = kendo.template($("#itemTemplate").html());
combo.template = template;
combo.refresh();
```

but no luck. Items are re-rendered (template is applied), but combobox is loosing core functionality

Answer (score 5):

I was able to do it with the setOptions method.

```
var combo = $("#combo").data("kendoComboBox");
var template = kendo.template($("#itemTemplate").html());
combo.setOptions({ template: template});
```